# Python Dictionary print value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm new to programming and I don't understand what happens. Can someone explain what's going on?

```
>>> primes = {1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 7, 7: 17}
>>> primes[4]
7
>>> primes[primes[4]]
17
```

Why does `primes[primes[4]]` result in 17?

Comment: This code is invalid, you missed an `=` after the `primes variable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the dictionary `primes = {1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 7, 7: 17}`, `primes[4]` results in 7.

When evaluating the expression `primes[primes[4]]`, Python has to evaluate `primes[4]` first, which, as we have seen, is 7.

So `primes[primes[4]]` is equivalent to `primes[7]`.

I hope you can see that, given the above dictionary, `primes[7]` results in 17.

Answer (score 0):

To start, the `primes` variable is a [Python dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). So let's start by looking at an example:

A dictionary in Python defines key-value pairs. For example, say we have an "ages" dictionary:

```py
ages = {
    "James": 20,
    "Mike": 13
}
```

With this data structure, if I wanted to get James' age, I'd say `ages['james']` and this value would be an integer, `20`.

Well, the same applies to your structure here, except instead of strings for the keys, you have integers. So let's take a look:

```py
primes = {
    1: 2, 
    2: 3, 
    4: 7, 
    7: 17
}
```

If we want to get the `17`, we'd go ahead and say `primes[7]`, as the integer 7 is referring to the number 17.